# How to fetch background color (RGB) from window class [WinAPI & c#]

Tags: c#, winapi

Please help, how to extract window background color from window handle (need RGB values) ...

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetSysColorBrush(int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassLong")]
    static extern uint GetClassLong32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassLongPtr")]
    static extern IntPtr GetClassLong64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LOGBRUSH
    {
        public uint lbStyle;
        public uint lbColor; // COLORREF
        public int lbHatch; //
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetObject(IntPtr hgdiobj, int cbBuffer, out LOGBRUSH brush);
```

Creating transparent layered window:

```
        const uint WINDOW_STYLE = 0x8000000     //WS_DISABLED
                                | 0x10000000    //WS_VISIBLE
                                | 0x80000000;   //WS_POPUP

        const uint WINDOW_EX_STYLE = 0x8000000  //WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
                                   | 0x80000    //WS_EX_LAYERED
                                   | 0x80       //WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW -> Not in taskbar
                                   | 0x8        //WS_EX_TOPMOST
                                   | 0x20;      //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        Random rnd = new Random();
        this.Handle = CreateWindowEx(
            WINDOW_EX_STYLE,
            "#32770",
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(rnd.Next(20)), // Replace("-", string.Empty)
            WINDOW_STYLE,
            this.X,
            this.Y,
            this.Width,
            this.Height,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero);
```

Fetch BG color:

```
        IntPtr r;
        const int GCL_HBRBACKGROUND = (-10);
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            r = new IntPtr((long)GetClassLong32(this.Handle, GCL_HBRBACKGROUND));
        else
            r = GetClassLong64(this.Handle, GCL_HBRBACKGROUND);

        LOGBRUSH logBrush;
        int ret = GetObject(r, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LOGBRUSH)), out logBrush);
```

When try get bg from window created on predefined window class name "#32770" -  i get r = 0x00000000, anyone have working snippet for this task ?

Right BG color for "#32770"

```
        const int COLOR_BTNFACE = 15;
        int bgColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE);

        const int COLOR_MENU = 4;
        int bgColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE);
```

How i get same color from window class?

Comment: why you think that it must return not 0 ?

Comment: Why would that be useful, with [Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187.aspx) and all? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: ok, how i can get RGB background from 0x00 ? Color need for transparency key into SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0x00F0F0F0, 255, 1 | 2); BG color on my PC for class "#32770" is 0x00F0F0F0 ...

Comment: @haashimat - Messagebox have no solid background - if you look it use `GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW)` for paint top and `GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU)` for paint bottom

Comment: @RbMm - in that case fetching bg color from window class is not possible ?

Comment: @haashimat - i simply check `GetClassLongPtrW(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND);` and got 0 - this is not used. what sense when in any case background paints with 2 colors.

Comment: Background brushes do not necessarily have to be solid. They can be pattern brushes, or image brushes, or even `NULL`, in which case no brush is used and the window in question draws its own background. And you're getting `NULL`! Are you trying to make a window you don't own layered? If you own the window, then you already know the background color — check your registration and window procedure.